# filling web form automatically - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome-extension, autofill

I need to open some forms which are opened  for limited time only. Sometimes  it will open for 5 minutes a day and form itself will take 10 minutes to fill as it has 50+ fields. I am thinking to make "Google Chrome extension "   cloning the original form and have one button "Autofill". As soon as I click on autofill it will  pass data from extension form to website form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you could use script injection, like run some function from console, the function retrieves those forms using js selectors and changes those input values, after that the function causes artificial submit button click.

See this article for farther information - [Chrome extension execute script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)